# Error en llamada PUT angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, restful

Tengo un problema con una llamada PUT en AngularJS.

Al realizar la llamada hacia la API al pulsar un botón, realiza una primera petición, pero seguidamente realiza una segunda, con los mismos parámetros, lo cuál me genera en error en la respuesta.

**Llamada API**

```
$http.put("http://192.168.20.14:8089/api/v1/ContratoPotencial/?Contratacion_ContratosPotencialesAPIDTO={\"IdEmpresa\": 2,\"IdUsuario\": 1}")
    .then(function successCallback (response) {
      console.log("Insertado! ");
      console.log(response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log("HAY ERROR");
    });
```

En ambos casos entrar al success, el problema es que en la primera llamada inserta el usuario y claro, al realizarse la segunda me devuelve el error de que ese usuario ya existe.

**ERROR EN CONSOLA**

En consola de Chrome veo lo siguiente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis aparece una llamada donde el origen es el main.min.js, pero lo extraño es que seguidamente aparece una llamda de un origen "other" que yo no lanzo y es la que me esta estropeando la comunicación.

Comment: ¿Has probado a trazar con las herramientas de desarrollo de tu navegador a ver efectivamente está entrando dos veces?

Comment: Por lo que he estado viendo, una es la OPTIONS y la otra la PUT. Estoy intentando eliminar la llamada OPTIONS para evitar ese error, pero no puedo de momento.

Answer (score 1):

Las peticiones OPTIONS no es ninguna manera un fallo de AngularJS, al contrario, estas favorecen el comunicado de recursos cruzados (APIs).

> El estándar de Intercambio de Recursos de Origen Cruzado trabaja
>   añadiendo nuevos encabezados HTTP que permiten a los servidores
>   describir el conjunto de orígenes que tienen permiso de leer la
>   información usando un explorador web.  Adicionalmente, para métodos de
>   solicitud HTTP que causan efectos secundarios en datos del usuario
>   (ien particular, para otros métodos HTTP que GET, o para la
>   utilización de POST con algunos tipos MIME), ***la especificación sugiere
>   que los exploradores "verifiquen" la solicitud***, solicitando métodos
>   soportados desde el servidor con un método de solicitud HTTP OPTIONS,
>   y luego, con la "aprobación" del servidor, enviar la verdadera
>   solicitud con el método de solicitud HTTP verdadero. Los servidores
>   pueden también notificar a los clientes cuando sus "credenciales"
>   (incluyendo Cookies y datos de autenticación HTTP) deben ser enviados
>   con solicitudes.

De recomendación permite todas las entradas (CORS) por este tipo de peticiones en tu servicio web.